# A card game with a mat on the table and chips in the kitty

Tags: identify-this-game, playing-cards

We used to play a card game with a mat on the table. We had to put chips in the kitty and also in 8 other piles on the mat.
Whoever won the hand got the kitty.
What's the name of this game?

Comment: We will likely need more information in order to identify this game.

Answer (score 3):

My best guess is [Tripoley](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/4853/tripoley). The main pictures on Board Game Geek show a plastic version, but [this image shows a version with a mat](https://boardgamegeek.com/image/2207799/tripoley). There is a Kitty pile, and 8 other piles. Each hand has a Hearts phase, a Poker phase, and a Rummy phase.

[image]

Comment: This was exactly my guess when I read it

Comment: We called it Rummy Royal, but same game (the BGG page lists it as an alternate name).

Answer (score 1):

In a similar vein to Gregor, my best guess would be [Rummoli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rummoli).

Players of Rummoli commonly use a plastic mat (though nicer versions exist) that is separated into 8 sections with a kitty pile in the middle.

Play consists of a hand of cards being dealt to each of the 2-8 players, followed by a poker phase then a Rummoli phase. The First player to play all their cards in the Rummoli phase gets to take the kitty.

Rummoli Mat:
[image: Rummoli Mat]
Vintage Rummoli Box:
[image: Vintage Box]